# Python tic tac toe detecting cheating

Tags: python

So for now I have written a simple Tic tac toe game. I haven't even used all the functions I made but here is my question:
How can I determine if the player places a 1 or 2 where there already is one, I think I know how to do this, but how can I then put them back at the "Input your number" prompt if they enter an illegal character or they try to overwrite an already placed 1 or 2.

Also is there a more compact way to do this?

Here is the code for the game:

```
nr = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
keepGoing = True

def checkP1():
    if nr[0] and nr[1] and nr[2] or nr[3] and nr[4] and nr[5] or nr[6] and nr[7] and nr[8] or nr[0] and nr[3] and \
       nr[6] or nr[1] and nr[4] and nr[7] or nr[2] and nr[5] and nr[8] or nr[0] and nr[4] and nr[8] or nr[2] and nr[4] and nr[6] == 1:
        print("P1 Wins")
        keepGoing = False
        return keepGoing



def checkP2():
    if nr[0] and nr[1] and nr[2] or nr[3] and nr[4] and nr[5] or nr[6] and nr[7] and nr[8] or nr[0] and nr[3] and \
       nr[6] or nr[1] and nr[4] and nr[7] or nr[2] and nr[5] and nr[8] or nr[0] and nr[4] and nr[8] or nr[2] and nr[4] and nr[6] == 2:
        print("P2 Wins")
        keepGoing = False
        return keepGoing

def Game():
    while keepGoing:
        PrintBoard()
        in1 = 0
        in2 = 0
        in1 = input("Please enter the number of the position you want to put your symbol P1.")
        nr[int(in1)-1] = 1
        check = checkP1()
        if check == 0:
            PrintBoard()
            break
        in2 = input("Please enter the number of the position you want to put your symbol P2.")
        check = checkP2()
        if check == 0:
            PrintBoard()
            break
        nr[int(in2)-1] = 2

def PrintBoard():
    print("",nr[0],nr[1],nr[2],"\n",nr[3],nr[4],nr[5],"\n",nr[6],nr[7],nr[8])

def Reset():
    nr = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

    keepGoing = True
```

Comment: You should at least use `all()` to test for a winner, your `if` clauses are a mess. column Y: `all(nr[Y::3])`, row X: `all(nr[X:X+3])`, diagonals: `all(nr[::4])` and `all(nr[2:8:2])`

Comment: @CoDEmanX I forgot to state I am beginner, I don't really know a lot yet. I was trying what I can do with my current resources.

Comment: @CoDEmanX I actually stopped learning for a while. Now when I look at this I get your point. I know that lists can take 2 arguments like list[x:y] but what happens if you give them 3 arguments like you did? list[x:y:z] What does it mean?

Comment: The third argument is the step value, so you can read [2:8:2] as "start at 2, count up to 8 (exclusive) in steps of 2". `list(range(9))[2:8:2]` or `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8][2:8:2]` returns `[2, 4, 6]`. `[::4]` means "return every 4th element", which is `[0, 4, 8]` here. https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#slice

Comment: @CoDEmanX I get it, the thing is I don't see a way that I could use this to make it more compact. I understand the way that it should work I just don't see a way to do it in code. It would be awesome if you could rewrite my check statements and show me what they should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of how slices can be used to determine the winner:

```
def same(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    start_val = it.__next__()
    for val in it:
        if val != start_val:
            return
    if start_val != 0:
        return start_val

nr = [0] * 9

nr[1] = 1
nr[2] = 2
nr[4] = 2
nr[6] = 2
nr[7] = 1
nr[8] = 1

for i in range(0, len(nr), 3):
    print(nr[i:i+3])

winner = (
    same(nr[0:3]) or same(nr[3:6]) or same(nr[6:9]) or
    same(nr[0::3]) or same(nr[1::3]) or same(nr[2::3]) or
    same(nr[::4]) or same(nr[2:-1:2])
)

if winner is not None:
    print("Player %i won!" % winner)
```

`same()` is a helper function that checks if all elements of an iterable have the same value, and if so, return that value unless it is `0` (so we only catch `1`s and `2`s by players).

You see the patterns in the slice notations, they could be easily scaled by using for-loops.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question

> how can I then put them back at the `"Input your number"` prompt if they enter an illegal character or they try to overwrite an already placed `1` or `2`

I would make a function to do this:

```
def get_valid_input(board):
    while True:
        try:
            move = int(input("Please enter the number of the position you want to put your symbol."))
        except ValueError:
            print("Input must be an integer number.")
        else:
            if move not in range(1, 10):
                print("Move must be 1-9.")
            elif board[move-1] in (1, 2):
                print("Location already used.")
            else:
                return move
```

This will continue until whichever player is currently going gives a valid `move`:

```
in1 = get_valid_input(nr)
```

A few more general pointers:

- Your current checking for a winner doesn't work - `if a or b == c` doesn't do what you think it does (see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/if-x-or-y-or-z-blah)). For example, `nr[0] and nr[1] and nr[2] == 2` actually tests `bool(nr[0]) and bool(nr[1]) and (nr[2] == 2)`; as long as the last value is two and the other two aren't zero, it will be `True`. CoDEmanX's suggestions in the comments will be useful here.
- Using the flag `keepgoing` isn't very Pythonic; I would make a function `game_over(board)` that returns `True` if the game is finished (either a win or a draw) and `False` otherwise, then the overall loop becomes `while True: ... if game_over(board): break`.
- Rather than relying on scope to access variables, pass what you need explicitly (e.g. the `board` argument to `get_valid_input` and `game_over`). Getting rid of `keepgoing` removes one of your global variables, but you could take the `board` as an argument to you other functions and `return` as appropriate. Alternatively, consider making a `class` to hold the `board` and all the functions.

Comment: I really don't understand your 2 first bulleted points. I don't know if that is bad but I am just a beginner in python. As your code makes complete sense I don't really understand what the text below it means.

Comment: I have added more to the comments. Have you read the linked question? If you don't understand the terms, try a web search for them.